# Flags Enum in binary

Tags: c#, enums

I met something very strange and i can't understand why it happens. I make this enum :

```
 [Flags]
public enum EnumMoveCommand
{
    None = 0x0,
    Up = 0x1,
    Right = 0x2,
    Bottom = 0x4,
    Left = 0x8,
    LeftClick = 0x16,
    RightClick = 0x32,
    Vertical = Up | Bottom,
    Horizontal = Left | Right,
    Move = Up | Right | Left | Bottom
}
```

So i can use it like this :

```
 if ((commands & EnumMoveCommand.Left) != EnumMoveCommand.None)
        {
            MoveToDo.X -= this.speed.X * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if ((commands & EnumMoveCommand.Right) != EnumMoveCommand.None)
        {
            MoveToDo.X += this.speed.X * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if ((commands & EnumMoveCommand.Up) != EnumMoveCommand.None)
        {
            MoveToDo.Y -= this.speed.Y * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if ((commands & EnumMoveCommand.Bottom) != EnumMoveCommand.None)
        {
            MoveToDo.Y += this.speed.Y * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if ((commands & EnumMoveCommand.Horizontal) != EnumMoveCommand.None && (commands & EnumMoveCommand.Vertical) != EnumMoveCommand.None)
        {
            MoveToDo.X = (float)(Math.Cos(45) * MoveToDo.X);
            MoveToDo.Y = (float)(Math.Sin(45) * MoveToDo.Y);
        }
```

But RightClick with value 0x32 doesn't work, for example :

```
((EnumMoveCommand.RightClick & EnumMoveCommand.Right) != EnumMoveCommand.None)=true
```

How 0x32 & 0x2 != 0x0 ?

Thanks

### EDIT

Okei so it s hex and not dec, now here is my code who works :

```
 None = 0x0,
    Up = 0x1,
    Right = 0x2,
    Bottom = 0x4,
    Left = 0x8,
    LeftClick = 0x10,
    RightClick = 0x20,
    Vertical = Up | Bottom,
    Horizontal = Left | Right,
    Move = Up | Right | Left | Bottom
```

Thanks all

### EDIT 2

```
    [Flags]
public enum EnumMoveCommand
{
    None = 0,
    Up = 1<<0, //1
    Right = 1<<1, //2
    Bottom = 1<<2, //4
    Left = 1<<3, //8
    LeftClick = 1<<4, //16
    RightClick = 1<<5, //32
    Vertical = Up | Bottom,
    Horizontal = Left | Right,
    Move = Up | Right | Left | Bottom
}
```

Is better, thanks kalten

Comment: `0x16` and `0x32` are a bad sort of flags. One is 22, another is 50. You probably meant `0x10` and `0x20`.

Comment: 0x represents hex not dec so 0x16 != 16 dec, it is 0x10.

Comment: okey thanks ! I was 100% wrong :/

Comment: If kaltens answer helped you solve your problem please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumMoveCommand.RightClick` = `0x32` = `110010`

`EnumMoveCommand.Right`      = `0x2` =  `000010`

`110010` & `000010` = `000010`

So 
    ((EnumMoveCommand.RightClick & EnumMoveCommand.Right) != EnumMoveCommand.None)==true

If you want avoid conflic between your enum values you can use the `<<` operator.

```
[Flags]
public enum EnumMoveCommand
{
    None = 0,
    Up = 1<<0, //1
    Right = 1<<1, //2
    Bottom = 1<<2, //4
    Left = 1<<3, //8
    LeftClick = 1<<4, //16
    RightClick = 1<<5, //32
    Vertical = Up | Bottom,
    Horizontal = Left | Right,
    Move = Up | Right | Left | Bottom
}
```

By the way you could use the `HasFlag` function like :

```
commands.HasFlag(EnumMoveCommand.RightClick)
```